# Getting related ACF fields of ACF relationship type

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, graphql, gatsby, advanced-custom-fields

I'm building out a WordPress site using Gatbsy, and I have a page on my WordPress site using the ACF relationship field to pick related post content.

From the rest API however, the WordPress page's relationship data (faculty_selector) does not contain the posts ACF fields, only relationship type data such as the post's wordpress_id.

My GraphQL query looks a little like this:

```
{
  wordpressPage(wordpress_id: {eq: 71}) {
    title
    content
    acf {
      faculty_title
      faculty_text
      faculty_selector {
        wordpress_id
      }  
    }
  }
  allWordpressAcfFaculty {
    edges {
      node {
        id
        wordpress_id
        acf {
          faculty_excerpt
          faculty_content
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and here is the result from that query

```
{
  "data": {
    "wordpressPage": {
      "title": "Bachelor’s in International  Hospitality Business",
      "content": "",
      "acf": {
        "faculty_title": "Quality teaching",
        "faculty_text": "<p style=\"text-align: center;\">Learn from some of the most respected individuals in the business</p>\n",
        "faculty_selector": [
          {
            "wordpress_id": 3752
          },
          {
            "wordpress_id": 3764
          },
          {
            "wordpress_id": 3765
          },
          {
            "wordpress_id": 3763
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    "allWordpressAcfFaculty": {
      "edges": [
        {
          "node": {
            "id": "b5b28341-43c1-56e2-9e6e-5862bdb026ce",
            "wordpress_id": 3765,
            "acf": {
              "faculty_excerpt": "<p>Jonathan Humphries</p>\n<p>Management Finance &#038; Accounting, Managerial Accounting, and Dissertation</p>\n",
              "faculty_content": "<h3>Jonathan Humphries</h3>\n<p><strong>Corporate Finance, Financial Management and Management Accounting</strong></p>\n<p>Debra has held positions at a number of hotel schools in the UK and Switzerland. She develops financial management programmes for the academic and training sector for senior managers, and has worked with a number of international hotel groups. Debra holds an MA in E-Learning and is qualified with the Chartered Institute of Management Accountants.</p>\n<p><strong>Program – Bachelors in International hotel management</strong></p>\n"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "node": {
            "id": "7c353f0a-0ad1-5792-a37a-3b44b7083282",
            "wordpress_id": 3764,
            "acf": {
              "faculty_excerpt": "<p>Dr. Emmanuel Jurczenko</p>\n<p>Management Finance &amp; Accounting, Managerial Accounting, and Dissertation</p>\n",
              "faculty_content": "<h3>Dr. Emmanuel Jurczenko</h3>\n<p><strong>Corporate Finance, Financial Management and Management Accounting</strong></p>\n<p>Debra has held positions at a number of hotel schools in the UK and Switzerland. She develops financial management programmes for the academic and training sector for senior managers, and has worked with a number of international hotel groups. Debra holds an MA in E-Learning and is qualified with the Chartered Institute of Management Accountants.</p>\n<p><strong>Program – Bachelors in International hotel management</strong></p>\n"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "node": {
            "id": "b8aec100-a516-57a7-94d0-69c267722f45",
            "wordpress_id": 3763,
            "acf": {
              "faculty_excerpt": "<p>Pia Huh</p>\n<p>Management Finance &#038; Accounting, Managerial Accounting, and Dissertation</p>\n",
              "faculty_content": "<h3>Pia Huh</h3>\n<p><strong>Corporate Finance, Financial Management and Management Accounting</strong></p>\n<p>Debra has held positions at a number of hotel schools in the UK and Switzerland. She develops financial management programmes for the academic and training sector for senior managers, and has worked with a number of international hotel groups. Debra holds an MA in E-Learning and is qualified with the Chartered Institute of Management Accountants.</p>\n<p><strong>Program – Bachelors in International hotel management </strong></p>\n"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "node": {
            "id": "71efc1f9-17b3-5a33-95e0-fd0228702f1a",
            "wordpress_id": 3752,
            "acf": {
              "faculty_excerpt": "<p>Debra Adams</p>\n<p>Management Finance &#038; Accounting, Managerial Accounting, and Dissertation</p>\n",
              "faculty_content": "<h3>Debra Adams</h3>\n<p><strong>Corporate Finance, Financial Management and Management Accounting</strong></p>\n<p>Debra has held positions at a number of hotel schools in the UK and Switzerland. She develops financial management programmes for the academic and training sector for senior managers, and has worked with a number of international hotel groups. Debra holds an MA in E-Learning and is qualified with the Chartered Institute of Management Accountants.</p>\n<p><strong>Program – Bachelors in International hotel management</strong></p>\n"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

So, my main problem is that when I query the `faculty_selector` on the page query I cannot retrieve the ACF fields of those posts.

But you can see those ACF fields (`faculty_excerpt, faculty_content`) present in the allWordpressAcfFaculty query.

Therefore, is there some way I can filter the `allWordpressAcfFaculty` by the page's dynamic post query?

Or, alternatively, is there some way on the WordPress side I can open up the ACF relationship type endpoint to contain this ACF data?

Thanks in advance for anyone who can offer any assistance.
Jamie

Comment: In ACF's Relationship field, can't you specify the return format as either `ID` or `WP_Post`? https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/relationship/

Comment: That's correct, you can select post_object, or post_id. I have post_object selected but it only allows data like 

```
faculty_selector {
        wordpress_id
        comment_count
        comment_status
        filter
        guid
        menu_order
        ping_status
        pinged
        post_author
        post_content
        post_content_filtered
        post_excerpt
        post_mime_type
        post_name
        post_parent
        post_password
        post_status
        post_title
        post_type
        to_ping
      }
```
so none of acf field options

Comment: So, to summarise, what I need is to figure some way to get that act field data in to faculty_selector object. Or, filter the allWordpressAcfFaculty by the faculty_selectors dynamic Wordpress_id values. Must be doable, right?